# Urbiduino-urbi-launch.exe stops responding

Tags: arduino

I'm tesing Urduino but can't make it work.

1. Run urbi.bat
2. Either run the .u script or loadModule("Arduino");
   Error: urbi-launch.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.

I have tried with Win8 64bit, Win 7 and XP SP3 32 bit. All have the same problem.
Thanks if you can find me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently only compatible with Urbi 2.7.5 We can use an older Urbi version.